# IIS ARR Rewrite URL Path as Query String Parameter

Tags: azure, iis, arr

I want to convert,

http://domain/something/another?param1=value1

to

http://domain/?paramz=something&paramy=another&param1=value1

with ARR IIS LB in Azure.

Comment: When a user goes to http://domain/something/another?param1=value1 should the server execute http://domain/?paramz=something&paramy=another&param1=value1 or should the user's URL change? 
Any specific reason you want ARR to do this vs URL Rewrite module?

Comment: Server should execute (rewrite) domain/?paramz=something&paramy=another&param1=value1

Comment: Should this rule match only URLs in this format `http://domain/XXXX/YYYY?param1=ZZZZZ` where XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ can be any string?

Comment: yes. They are valid uri encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the URL rewrite module to do this, examples can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work for you:

```
<rule name="ARR Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="param1=" />
    </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/?paramz={R:1}&amp;paramy={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />                   
 </rule>
```

It is checking if URL have two segments (`/something/another`) and query string has parameter `param1` in query string then it's rewriting  as you want